# How do i filter one list from another list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote the following query to filter query.

I used `First()` which is causing the issue I didn't notice earlier because `Entity2` is also a collection. It only filters the first Id.

```
query = query.Where(x => filter.Ids.Contains(x.Entity2.Select(y => y.testId).First()));
```

Please suggest how I can use contains to check all testId property of Entity2 ?

> Basically x.Entity2.Select(y => y.testId) is list of Ids which i want
>   to check whether they contains in filter.Ids or not.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, `filter.Ids` and `x.Entity2.Select(y => y.testId)` are both lists if Ids, and you want to make sure that all Ids from `x.Entity2` are also in `filter.Ids`. In that case, you want the following:

```
var result = query.Where(x => x.Entity2.Count(y => filter.Ids.Contains(y.testId)) == x.Entity2.Count);
```

What we are doing here is we are counting for each element of `query`, the number of Ids that are both in it's `Entity2` and in `filter.Ids`. If that number is equal to the total number of Ids in `Entity2`, then we include that in the result.

Answer (score 0):

For your above query you can also use `Any()` and `Contains()` both , it will work as
According to you filter is collection which has Ids and Entity2 both are also collection , so assuming that i wrote this,

`query = query.Where(x => filter.Where(a=> a.Entity2.Any(y=> a.Ids.Contains(y.testId));`

but in your query also you can remove `First()` and can use `ToList()` but it will be throw `OutofMemoryException` , if data is large.